# Create mock object with a member function that returns a class attribute

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I want to patch `requests.get` to make my tests independent from network connections. The mocking method should return a `Response` object with valid json and status code. I created the mocking function which defines a new MockResponse class with everything I need. *This solution works as intended.* It is the commented out section.

However, pylint warned that the class only has one public function and I've been trying to remove that warning by creating a Mock Object with `mock.Mock`, however I can't seem to make it work. Is it possible to do this mocking without creating a "small" class?

EDIT: Waket Zheng improved my WebTools code with an edit, and used a property method `ok` - which I also have to mock and now I've got 2 class methods so the pylint warning does not show anymore.

EDIT TLDR: An edit to the question provided an alternative solution, however not the solution to my question.

Test:

```py
class TestWebtools(TestCase):
    VALID_TEST_CASES = [
        ('https://testurl.com/simple.json', {"value": "someValue"}, "someValue"),
        ('https://testurl.com/valueDoesNotExist.json', {}, ""),
        ('https://testurl.com/error1', None, ""),
    ]

    def _mocked_requests_get(*args, **_):
        # class MockResponse:
        #     def __init__(self, json_data, status_code):
        #         self.json_data = json_data
        #         self.status_code = status_code
        #
        #     def json(self):
        #         return self.json_data
        #
        #     @property
        #     def ok(self):
        #         return self.status_code == 200

        MockResponse = mock.Mock()
        MockResponse.json.return_value = MockResponse.json_data

        for url, value, _ in TestWebtools.VALID_TEST_CASES:
            if args[0] == url:
                return MockResponse(json_data=value, status_code=200)

        return MockResponse(json_data=None, status_code=404)

    @mock.patch('requests.get', _mocked_requests_get)
    def test_download_json(self):
        for url, expected, _ in self.VALID_TEST_CASES:
            self.assertEqual(expected, download_json(url))
```

WebTools:

```py
def download_json(fromUrl: str) -> Optional[dict]:
    response = requests.get(fromUrl, timeout=5)
    if response.ok:
        return response.json()
    return None
```

Comment: Why not use the responses library which is meant for mocking of this sort?  See https://pypi.org/project/responses/

Comment: because I didn't know it existed. Thanks, I'll have a look!